# Should we edit the rule "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here"?

Tags: feature-request

Since I'm a question reader and I found this question ([InvalidOperationException vs. ArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434842/invalidoperationexception-vs-argumentexception)) which was closed by the rule:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

He asked (for who is lazy to read the question):

> I know the summaries and descriptions.
>
> But what if the ARGUMENT is in an INVALID STATE?
>
> I think the ArgumentException is more appropriate because the InvalidOperationException documentation says that the object itself on what the method is called has to be in an invalid state, right?

And there was a good answer:

[image: 1]

Since it's a good answer, there was no idea/suggestion for that answer but having 11 upvotes.

So, based on this answer, we can say: the question was **NOT** `ambiguous, vague, incomplete....`. That logic, I think we should edit this rule.

How can an unclear question be found and read 1592 times?

Thanks for support!

Comment: This close reason does not exist anymore (since several years now).

Comment: 1600 views in 5 years isn't a lot in my book.

Comment: In the comments there, we also get to see a great example of how the (now removed) "Too Localized" reason used to be used, by a commenter arguing that since "actual users" don't care whether exceptions are used in a semantically-correct way, questions about the semantics of exceptions are inherently off-topic. I guess the 1613 viewers since then weren't "actual" people. The ability to use that close reason like that - to say "I don't personally care about your question and therefore infer that nobody else does, and therefore it shouldn't be allowed to be answered" - is why it was removed.

Comment: throw new NotARealQuestionException(question);

Answer (score 1):

The close reason you are referring to ("not a real question") [has been removed in 2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/).

Just for the records: "Am I right?" is also today not a good question. For the specific case, the question would be way better if it was written like

> I know the summaries and descriptions of the two exceptions.
>
> But which of the two exceptions should be used when the ARGUMENT itself is in an INVALID STATE?
>
> I think the ArgumentException is more appropriate because the InvalidOperationException documentation says that the object itself on which the method is called has to be in an invalid state.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like SO didn't update everything after making changes.

Comment: They didn't change the close message for questions that were closed before the change. But it is impossible to close questions nowadays with this reason.

Comment: I mean: `var posts = _dbContext.Questions.Where(x => x.Status == PostStatus.Closed && x.CloseReason == CloseReason.NotARealQuestion);` Then, removing the `closed` state because it's valid.

Comment: No, that's not what happened. They only changed the close reasons. They did not reopen any questions since this would have opened a lot of rightfully closed questions too.

Comment: @Andrew That would mean bulk-reopening a ton of old questions and that's not something we'd want to do I think.

Comment: -1; I see nothing at all wrong with asking "am I right?". Indeed, if the question were asked with your suggested wording (which still speculates about what the answer is, but omits the explicit question at the end), it'd risk getting a *different* bunch of critics saying *"But you've already answered your own question! So what is it you don't understand, exactly?"* and voting to close the question as unclear on that basis. These superficial features of an asker's wording, which don't ultimately change what's being asked, shouldn't flip our entire judgement of whether a question is good or not.

Comment: @MarkAmery Argreed. I like the question which has the line: `My question is: ....`. And I think the sub question `am I right?` will be used in the case *This is my idea..... I think so but I haven't tried it before, is it right?*. Then... *This question may be closed because OP never tried it before ^^!*